# Add color overlay to section

Tags: html, css

I would like to use a semi-transparent color overlay on my html section, but it does not cover the entire section. This is what I got so far:

```css
#main {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/23/08/00/bow-lake-5854210_960_720.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#main::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="main">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h1>This is a text block</h1>
                <p>This will only contain text which the user can edit from the admin via a text editor. Paddings, bg color/image are controlled via css file.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic ratione saepe quidem quo corrupti rem accusantium ex dolorem explicabo odio quae quos illo, voluptates maiores.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h1>This is a text block</h1>
                <p>This will only contain text which the user can edit from the admin via a text editor. Paddings, bg color/image are controlled via css file.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic ratione saepe quidem quo corrupti rem accusantium ex dolorem explicabo odio quae quos illo, voluptates maiores.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

The problem is the color overlay isn't displaying correctly all the time and in all screen sizes because I'm using padding top and bottom in the `#main`. For large screensizes it helps if I add some margin top to the before element, but in smaller screen sizes it won't help. How can I make sure the color overlay always covers the entire section regardless of the screensize and if I use padding top and bottom in the `#main`?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this ruleset to `#main::before`:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Also, remove `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set `top: 0` on your pseudo element.

```css
#main {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/23/08/00/bow-lake-5854210_960_720.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#main::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="main">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h1>This is a text block</h1>
                <p>This will only contain text which the user can edit from the admin via a text editor. Paddings, bg color/image are controlled via css file.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic ratione saepe quidem quo corrupti rem accusantium ex dolorem explicabo odio quae quos illo, voluptates maiores.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h1>This is a text block</h1>
                <p>This will only contain text which the user can edit from the admin via a text editor. Paddings, bg color/image are controlled via css file.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic ratione saepe quidem quo corrupti rem accusantium ex dolorem explicabo odio quae quos illo, voluptates maiores.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set top, bottom, left and right position for your overlay instead of width and height, like this:

```css
#main {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/23/08/00/bow-lake-5854210_960_720.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#main::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="main">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h1>This is a text block</h1>
                <p>This will only contain text which the user can edit from the admin via a text editor. Paddings, bg color/image are controlled via css file.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic ratione saepe quidem quo corrupti rem accusantium ex dolorem explicabo odio quae quos illo, voluptates maiores.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h1>This is a text block</h1>
                <p>This will only contain text which the user can edit from the admin via a text editor. Paddings, bg color/image are controlled via css file.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic ratione saepe quidem quo corrupti rem accusantium ex dolorem explicabo odio quae quos illo, voluptates maiores.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

It will expand overlay over its whole parent. Other way is to set position at some corner, e.g. top and left and width and height to 100%.

Better doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning)